# How to re-prompt a user after an invalid input?

Tags: python

> Write a function named getBetween.
>
> getBetween should take two arguments: low and high.  getBetween should
>   prompt the user for an integer between low and high, inclusive (in
>   other words, greater than or equal to low and less than or equal to
>   high).    If the user enters a  number that is not in the proper
>   range, getBetween should tell the user that they made an error and ask
>   them again.  If the user enters something  that is not a number,
>   getBetween should detect this (by using  exceptions), inform the user
>   of their error, and ask them again. When  the user enters an
>   acceptable answer, return it.

So what I can't figure out how to do is to re-prompt the user if the input number is not in range. Here's my code:

```
while True:
    try:
      low = int(input("Enter a low number: "))
      high = int(input("Enter a high  number: "))
    except ValueError:
     print("Invalid Input")
     continue
    else:
      break
var = false
def getBetween(low,high):
  while True:
    try:
      number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
     print("Invalid Input")
     continue
    else:
      break 
  if low<number<high:
    print(number)
  else:
       print("This input is not in range.")
getBetween(low,high)
```

Comment: Something like `if invalid_input: input("try again")`?

Comment: Just move the "This input is not in range" block into the While loop above it. That way it won't BREAK out, and you can add the continue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "re-prompt". Let the while loop repeat itself.

```
  while True:
    try:
      number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
      if low<number<high:
        print(number)
        break  # if you want to stop the loop
      else:
        print("This input is not in range.")
        # implicit continue
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid Input")
      continue  # not really needed
```